# Laravel symlink()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-permissions, permission-denied

I get this error:

```
In Filesystem.php line 228:
symlink(): Permission denied
```

whenever I run:

```
php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy
```

Voyager installs smoothly but with no images.
Please how do I fix this?

Comment: you are running your app in server or local ? are you sure you server support symlink() function ?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if my server supports symlink(), but i'm running laravel on my android phone using Termux.

Comment: PHP version ^7.2 is installed. And I can safely run:
php artisan serve